# Animate path in UWP

Tags: animation, uwp

In a UWP application, I want to animate paths (e.g. composed from Bézier segments) as if it was drawn with a pen, i.e. in the example

```xml
<Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Black" Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175" />
```

it should start incrementally drawing a Bézier segment from (100, 200) to (400, 175) using the given control points. TBH, I am completely lost as I have not found a property on `Path` that could be used as control variable. I first thought I could build something using `PointAnimationUsingPath`, but this is not available in UWP. Is there any way to achieve this, preferably without evaluating the Bézier curve manually in key frames?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) with the [CanvasAnimatedControl](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasAnimatedControl.htm).

Comment: I have never used Win2D and the `CanvasAnimatedControl` seems only to be the skeleton for building the animation manually. However, after browsing the documentation for a while, `CanvasGeometry.ComputePointOnPath` looks promising - need to check whether I piece something together with the two ...